# How to pass a JS variable as a parameter to a Python function and store Python output as a JS variable?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, node.js, dom

I'm trying to get my html+JS file to communicate with my python file, but I'm stuck on how to take a variable from the JS, use it as a parameter in a python function, and then store the python's output as a JS variable. I'm not able to provide my actual implementation, but here is a skeleton of what I'm trying to do:

`app.py`

```
def foo(input):
    #lots of computation
    return result
```

`index.html`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Type here: <span id="field"></span></p>
<script>
var fieldSpan = document.getElementById('field');

var inputData= fieldSpan.textContent;

var outputData = /* Something that essentially calls the function foo(inputData) and returns its output*/
</script>
```

I don't have very much experience with JQuery or NodeJS, but I've come across some things saying to use flask(?) and ajax(??) to get the JS and python to talk to each other. Any help on that front would be really helpful.

Now, what I was able to get working was to use nodeJS to communicate with my python file. Here's what the JS looks like:
`test.js`

```js
const spawner = require('child_process').spawn;

//string
const data_in = 'Send this to python script.';

console.log('Data sent to python script: ', data_in);
const python_process = spawner('python', ['./app.py',data_in]);

python_process.stdout.on('data',(data) => {
    console.log('Data received from python script:', data.toString());
});
```

(credit to [Apes in Capes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSAFVMaaH-w))

running `node test.js` returns exactly what I want, but I'm not sure how to integrate this into the html textbox, so that the `data_in` can be equal to the user's input. So if instead of using the whole flask/ajax system, it's possible to use nodeJS, that'd be fantastic, but in either case, I just need to figure out how to get the files communicating. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## APIs

I believe the traditional way to accomplish what you want is to **create an API** (Application Programming Interface). People have suggested things like [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) and [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/) because they are tools that can interact with APIs.

Communication between your `app.py` and `test.js` is relatively easy because **they both run on your computer**. The script on the HTML file, however, **runs in the browser** and it (thankfully) can't do something like tell your computer to run `app.py`. Imagine if any website you open could tell your computer to run a program.

In a simplified manner, an API specifies ways to access the functionality of a certain application. For example:

- [placekitten.com](https://placekitten.com/) specifies that if you visit something like https://placekitten.com/200/300, they will send you a picture of a kitten with width 200 and height 300.
- [zenquotes.io](https://zenquotes.io/) specifies that if you visit https://zenquotes.io/api/today, they will send you a quote from an influential figure (quote changes each day).

## Creating a local web API using Flask

To solve your problem, your API can specify that if you visit `somewhere` you will get the result of running the `foo` function.

As the `foo` function is the central part of the API and it is written in Python, I'll show you an example on how to create an API using Flask, which takes 0 effort to integrate with Python code. You could use, for example [Express](https://expressjs.com/) to create the API, but integrating with Python would take some effort.

#### Defining `somewhere`

We'll create a local web API. This means that `somewhere` will be `localhost`, and as we're using Flask and Flask likes to sit at port `5000`, our `somewhere` is more precisely `http://localhost:5000`. We can make Flask sit somewhere else, but we won't bother.

To organize things we'll define that to run the `foo` function you need to interact with the **endpoint** `/api/run_foo`. In the end, our `somewhere` will be **`http://localhost:5000/api/run_foo`**

#### Passing parameters

You mentioned the need to pass a JS parameter to the python function. This can be done in many ways. I'll show one of them (if you checked the kitten example, you've already seen one way to do this).

This API will do one thing: allow other applications to **use the `foo` function**. They will be able to **pass a parameter called `param_to_foo`**, and it will run `foo` with that parameter. Then it will **send back the result**.

Parameters will be passed via the URL, but in a way that's different from the kitten example. Instead of doing `http://localhost:5000/api/run_foo/100` to pass 100 to `foo`, we'll do `http://localhost:5000/api/run_foo?param_to_foo=100`. Notice the addition of the question mark and the format `name=value`. `param_to_foo` is a **url parameter**.

#### Sending the result back

To send back the result, we'll use the [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON#no_really_what_is_json) format. Flask makes it easy with a function called `jsonify`.

### Writing the API

You'll need to install `flask` and `flask_cors` to run the code that follows.

```bash
python -m pip install flask flask_cors
# or
pip install flask flask_cors
```

`app.py`

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


# your foo function
def foo(param):
    return f"From python. Received: {param}. Its double is: {param * 2}"


# Defining the behavior of the endpoint "/api/run_foo"
@app.route("/api/run_foo")
def this_function_name_doesnt_really_matter():
    foo_param = request.args.get("param_to_foo", type=int)

    data = {"result": foo(foo_param)}
    return jsonify(data)
```

Then start Flask with the command **`flask run`** in the same folder where `app.py` is. If the file is not called `app.py`, you'll have to run `flask --app <file name without .py> run`.

You can check if everything is working by visiting http://localhost:5000/api/run_foo?param_to_foo=50. You should see a JSON in your browser.

If everything works, we'll have an API as long as Flask is running. If you stop the Flask process, the API goes down.

### Using the API

Below is an HTML file that takes some input from the user, makes an API call using the received value and displays the API response.

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Introduction to APIs</title>
        <script>
            async function callAPI() {
                let param = document.getElementById("field").value
                const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/run_foo?param_to_foo=${param}`);
                const data = await response.json();

                document.getElementById("api-response").textContent = data["result"]

            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Introduction to APIs</h1>
        <label> Number to pass to foo:
            <input id="field" type="number">
        </label>
        <button onclick="callAPI()">Send</button>
        <p>API response:</p>
        <p id="api-response"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

It uses the some built-in JavaScript functionality ([Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)) to make a call to our API and wait for a response. You can open this file in your browser and as long as the Flask server is running, the API response should show up.